# docker run error environment variable contains whitespaces

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have environment variable file like follow name `.env-template`

```
export S3_BASE_FOLDER_URL="oa-eui-dev-plt-env-kpidev-oa"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=""
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-1"
export DB_HOST="host.docker.internal"
export DB_NAME="bcpdemo"
export DB_USER="SA"
export DB_PASS="1234Qwer!"
export BATCH_IMPORT_JOB_NAME=""
AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX=0
```

while running docker run command like

```
docker run --env-file env_template --name bcpbatchcontainer bcpbatchimage
```

It is shwoing follwoing error

```
docker: open env_template: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

If I pass env variable with `-e` it is not showing any problem. But I need to pass with file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) you have to use relative path (`./`).

This works for me:

```
docker run --env-file ./.env-template <your_image>
```

Also your `.env` file doesn't need `export`, this works:

```
S3_BASE_FOLDER_URL="oa-eui-dev-plt-env-kpidev-oa"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-1"
DB_HOST="host.docker.internal"
DB_NAME="bcpdemo"
DB_USER="SA"
DB_PASS="1234Qwer!"
BATCH_IMPORT_JOB_NAME=""
AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX=0
```

If you try to maintain `export` word it throws an error:

> docker: poorly formatted environment: variable 'export S3_BASE_FOLDER_URL' contains whitespaces.

Comment: it was for testing purpose to another shell script. I have removed the export. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue : just remove the "export "